# Include Font while pasting to Clipboard

Tags: c#, fonts, formatting, clipboard, string-formatting

I'm trying to include the font "KaiTi" while setting text on the clipboard, so that wherever I paste the data, the "KaiTi" Font will be the font that the text is in, inevitably keeping all of the data that I am pasting to the clipboard formatted the way that I want it too.

This is what I tried, I know it's off, but I don't know what to do..

```
            TextBox texter = new TextBox();
            texter.Text = strToClips;
            texter.Font = new Font("KaiTi", 10);
            Clipboard.SetText(texter.Text);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a RichTextBox. It puts rich text on the clipboard that includes formatting. Use its Copy() method.  Pasting back now also works automatically without any code.

Answer (score 0):

The richtextbox displayed the formatting OK, but I couldn't get Copy() to bring the font across. In the end I selected the text then sent a Ctrl-C character to copy it, as follows:-

```
myrichtextbox.SelectAll();
myrichtextbox.Focus();
SendKeys.Send("^C");
```